# Iterating and indexing through a dictionary Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary, for-loop, indexing

The code below goes through a dictionary and prints the subsets of the `dictionary` that includes `CompoundedAmount,TradingPair,talib_function`. However because of the nested for loop the `counter` gets reset as it goes through two sublevels to print the outputs. Instead of using a nested for loops how would I be able top get the `Expected Output` where `counter` does not reset and it goes through the `sets` in order?

```
def Indexing(dictionary):
    for index,Value in dictionary.items():
        for counter,(sets) in enumerate(Value):
            print("counter: ",  counter, "sets: ",sets)

    
dictionary = { 
 'RSI': [{'CompoundedAmount': 2,
          'TradingPair': 'BTCUSD',
          'talib_function': 'RSI'},
         {'CompoundedAmount': 2,
          'TradingPair': 'XRPUSD',
          'talib_function': 'RSI'}],
 'ROCR100': [{'CompoundedAmount': 2,
              'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT',
              'talib_function': 'ROCR100'}],
 'MOM': [{'CompoundedAmount': 2,
          'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT',
          'talib_function': 'MOM'}]}

Indexing(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
counter:  0 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BTCUSD', 'talib_function': 'RSI'}
counter:  1 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'XRPUSD', 'talib_function': 'RSI'}     
counter:  0 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'talib_function': 'ROCR100'}
counter:  0 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'talib_function': 'MOM'}
```

Expected output:

```
counter:  0 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BTCUSD', 'talib_function': 'RSI'}
counter:  1 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'XRPUSD', 'talib_function': 'RSI'}     
counter:  2 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'talib_function': 'ROCR100'}
counter:  3 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'talib_function': 'MOM'}
```

Comment: Instead of `enumerate()` you can maintain `counter` outside the first loop which will increment every time in second loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a different variable:

```
def Indexing(dictionary):
    count = 0
    for index, Value in dictionary.items():
        for sets in Value:
            count += 1
            print("counter: ",  count, "sets: ",sets)

Indexing(dictionary)

counter:  1 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BTCUSD', 'talib_function': 'RSI'}
counter:  2 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'XRPUSD', 'talib_function': 'RSI'}
counter:  3 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'talib_function': 'ROCR100'}
counter:  4 sets:  {'CompoundedAmount': 2, 'TradingPair': 'BCHUSDT', 'talib_function': 'MOM'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `enumerate` because `counter` is zero every time your nested loop starts.
You can use this one:

```
def Indexing(dictionary):
    counter = 0
    for index,Value in dictionary.items():
        for (sets) in Value:
            print("counter: ",  counter, "sets: ",sets)
            counter += 1
```